# map is not a function in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, testcafe

I am not able to use a map function inside a client function.

```
 export function availableAudioBitrates() {
  const getOptionNames = ClientFunction(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector('[data-testid=audioBitrate-setting]');
    const options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
    console.log(typeof options);
    //const values = [];
    const values = options.map((option) => option.TextContent);

    //options.forEach((option) => values.push(option.textContent));
    return values;
  });
  return getOptionNames();
}
```

I have "options.foreach" statement working, but with map function, it is throwing an error that options.map is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is a HTMLCollection, not an array.

Use `Array.form(select.querySelectorAll('option'))`.

```js
export function availableAudioBitrates() {
  const getOptionNames = ClientFunction(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector('[data-testid=audioBitrate-setting]');
    const options = Array.from(select.querySelectorAll('option'));
    console.log(typeof options);
    //const values = [];
    const values = options.map((option) => option.TextContent);

    //options.forEach((option) => values.push(option.textContent));
    return values;
  });
  return getOptionNames();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `options`, its either undefined or not an array. `.map()` requires an array to run, anything else will cause that error